# Issues with setting up Autodiscovery Auto-Configuration for Kubernetes integration in Datadog

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

I have recently updated DataDog to use a Cluster Agent. I am currently trying to set up the [Kubernetes integration](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-with-datadog/). This should be an auto discovered through the `auto_conf.yaml`. But for some reason when updating to the Cluster Agent we lost metrics through the kubernetes integration. My guess was to set it as a cluster check by adding `cluster_check:true` in the `auto_conf.yaml` file, but that did not work. I currently have it set up only on the node agents and configured just like it says in this [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/installation/?tab=daemonset). Is there something else that needs to be done to set up the Kubernetes integration with a Cluster Agent?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by adding `kubernetes-stat-core` via the following manifests. This is uses the [kube-state-metrics v2.0](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/kube-state-metrics-v2-monitoring-datadog/).

https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/main/Dockerfiles/manifests/kubernetes_state_core